# Update SCHED_NAME column in existing triggers/jobs in Quartz.NET database tables

Tags: quartz.net

I'm using Quartz with SqlServer database. Sometimes, there is a need to update `IScheduler.SchedulerName` during application launching and initialization, but as I noticed, after the update it doesn't see previously saved triggers/jobs in the database, because the ones have old `SchedulerName`. Thus, saved triggers will not be fired anymore, only new ones will be...

Nevertheless, you can directly update `SCHED_NAME` column using SQL, but maybe there is a built-in method to do it...

Thanks in advance.